# How can I copy a specific chapter page design?

Tags: book-design

I am trying to write notes on a subject and I want to view them also in book format. The sample of a book, which I saw impressive for reading is the following one. How to make such format of book including style of font and also type of titles of chapter, titles of sections etc. The Springer publishing company has produced lot of books of this format for undergraduates and I have seen such books impressive in their writing style.

The very basic step to write book is appeared as question earlier, it says to start with

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book} 
\begin{document}
\include{chapter1}
\end{document}
```

but I am interested in *its form* also.

Thanks in advance!.

> [image]

Comment: This question is very broad. Could you please show us your attempts? There are many questions how to style a book which you could start with.

Comment: OK, I agrree about broadness of question, but the starting I did was what I wrote the latex commands in above question. The other mathematical part I can handle with some effort, but I am finding tolls for making above style pages in book.

Comment: You can download latex class files from most (all?) of the major publishers who publish mathematics. For Springer have a look at https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/latex-template/1006. Personally, I prefer CUP: https://authornet.cambridge.org/information/elt/latex.asp. There's also https://tufte-latex.github.io/tufte-latex/ and many many others.

Comment: "...but I am finding tolls for making above style pages in book". Is that tolls, tools or trolls? :)

Comment: If you have any particular sample PDF as sample, then pass to me, I will create the LaTeX class file based on the sample PDF...

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic on this site as they usually do not revolve around an abstract issue.  Instead, [describe the problem](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: To the close-voters: wait a few days before closing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KSSY4.png. 
Let's give the OP time to refine his/her question!

Comment: Although you might find it exhausting to search for book designs and code snippets in LaTeX, you will find some. It will be appreciated on this site, if you do the first steps on your own and then ask for specific details.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt at recreating the chapters. There are several things which might break:

- two-digit chapter numbers will be too wide
- long chapter titles will mess up the vertical alignment

From here it isn't that difficult to change the section numbers. I'll leave this task to the OP or anyone else who'd like to comment …

Here is the code so far:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\definecolor{gray50}{gray}{0.5}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\dottedline[1][]{%
   \tikz[baseline]\draw[line width=3pt,dotted,line cap=round,dash pattern=on 0pt off 3\pgflinewidth, gray50](0,-1.2)--(0,1.8);%
}

% \titleformat{〈command〉}[〈shape〉]{〈format〉}{〈label〉}{〈sep〉}{〈before-code〉}[〈after-code〉]

\titleformat%
    {\chapter}% command
    [hang]% shape
    {\Huge\bfseries}% format
    {\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][4\baselineskip]{%
        \begin{minipage}{25mm}
            \raisebox{12mm}{\parbox{25mm}{\centering\fontsize{90}{90}\normalfont\bfseries\textcolor{gray50}{\thechapter}\\[4mm]\normalsize\bfseries\textcolor{gray50}{\so{CHAPTER}}}}%
        \end{minipage}\hspace{10mm}\dottedline
        }
    }% label
    {10mm}% sep
    {}% before-code
    []% after-code

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image: first chapter]

---

[image: second chapter]